# Setting a property as a primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to set a property as a primary key. What I mean is, I have a POCO object I'm trying to define a key for like this:

```
public class POCO
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    int Id;

    string Name;
    int Age;    
}
```

Then I'm trying to access it like this:

```
public static object ReturnKeyValue(this POCO poco)
{
    return poco.[PrimaryKey]; //should return Id 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [key] if you are talking about EF data annotation, please be more specific

Comment: I'm talking about identifying the key property from anywhere I am using the class.

Comment: Those classes are just carriers and don't need to know anything about the db.

Comment: @elvin It would be nice if they could somehow using the method I'm trying to use.

Comment: See my answer below, I think it is exactely what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the POCO class's PrimaryKey property be made public, with a getter and setter, like this?

```
public class POCO
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    string Name;
    int Age;
}
```

If so, then the following extension method should return the PrimaryKey field's value for any given POCO instance.

```
public static object ReturnKeyValue(this POCO poco)
{
    return (from p in poco.GetType().GetProperties()
            let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PrimaryKeyAttribute), true)
            where attr.Length == 1
            select p).First().GetValue(poco, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had something similar, which to which I found a solution yesterday, so I'm happy to share it.
Something you need to know is that what you're trying to do will never work when you have a composite key, which means, having a POCO object that has a primary key that conists out of more than 1 single element.

Let's say that I have the following class (POCO):

```
public class Person : EntityBase<int>
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the id of the entity.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public TKey Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the firstname.
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the <see cref="Manager"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework here, therefore the attribute that defines the Primary Key is called `Key` and not `PrimaryKey` as in your example.

Now, I do have class that acts a repository. That class hold all the objects of Person in an object, in my Test-scenario, it's holding those objects in an HashSet:

```
private readonly HashSet<TEntity> _entitiesCollection = new HashSet<TEntity>();
```

Where `TEntity` is offcourse the `Person` entity.

Further, this class does have a `List<PropertyInfo>' object, named`_keyProperties`, that will hold all the keys for the object.

Now, I do have a method that will find all the properties that act as a key for the given object:

```
 private void GetKeyProperties()
 {
     _keyProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
     var properties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties();

     foreach (var property in from property in properties from attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<KeyAttribute>() select property)
     { _keyProperties.Add(property); }
 }
```

No, you can for example select all your that matches a given value for the primary keys. This can be achieved with a method like:

```
protected virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
{
    if (keyValues.Length != _keyProperties.Count) throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect number of keys passed to find method");

    var keyQuery = this.AsQueryable();
    keyQuery = keyValues.Select((t, i) => i).Aggregate(keyQuery, (current, x) => current.Where(entity => _keyProperties[x].GetValue(entity, null).Equals(keyValues[x])));

    return keyQuery.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Or, for example, if you want to perform an update of an entity, you can execute the following:

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    // First the original entity is retrieve by searching the key, this item is then removed from the collection
    // Then a new item is being added to the collection.
    var original = Find(_keyProperties.Select(e => e.GetValue(entity)).ToArray());
    Detach(original);

    _entitiesCollection.Add(entity);
}
```

What this does is searching the original entity based on the primary key, remove that entity and then add the updated one again.

So, I hope this helps.